# Why is my Cycles render lighting squared when using GPU compute and smooth with CPU?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

The first image is when using GPU compute and the other is CPU
Why is the lighting squared on the GPU render?

[image: GPU]

[image: CPU]

GPU: EVGA RTX 2080 SUPER      //
CPU: i7- 8700k
thanks

Comment: Please use the tools from this site so that the images show as part of the post and users don't have to follow links just to understand your question. https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzn5b.png

Comment: seems like a bug. Other people using 2.8x with a gpu have also seen issues like this.